# Regular Expression - Select only one character if it's followed by another char

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace char '&' if it's not followed by '#'. For example in this string `"& hello &# world!"` I'd want to select only the first '&'.

So far I came up with this regex:

```
&[^#]
```

However, this selects 2 characters, whereas I want to only select the ampersand character.

Any help from RegExp Gurus would be appreciated.

BTW. It may be important: I want to use it in java replaceAll().

Many thanks,
Damo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  negative lookahead:

```
System.out.println("& hello &# world!&".replaceAll("&(?!#)", "&amp;"));
```

Prints:

```
&amp; hello &# world!&amp;
```

Comment: Accepted, because this was the first answer pointing towards negative lookahead. +1 to all other answers. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "&$ &# &s &";
String r = s.replaceAll("&([^#])|(&$)", "&amp;$1");
System.out.println("r = " + r);
```

prints:

```
r = &amp;$ &# &amp;s &amp;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Consider this simple code:

```
String str = "& &$ &# &s &#";
str = str.replaceAll("&(?!#)", "&amp;");
// assigns: &amp; &amp;$ &# &amp;s &#
```

This basically means replace `&` if **not followed by** `#`.

Answer (score 1):

- You could replaceAll &# by @# or any other improbable char sequence.
- Replace all & by what you want
- and replace back all @# by &#

Answer (score 1):

I think [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) applies here: `&(?!#)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
&(?!#)
```

> The negative lookahead construct is the pair of round brackets, with the opening bracket followed by a question mark and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial regex #.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Haven't tested it in java though